# Issue installing my own block in moodle 2.8.1

Tags: block, moodle

I created my own block by using the instructions as stated as in https://docs.moodle.org/dev/Blocks

But my created own block is not visible in the list of blocks available in moodle.

How can i add my own block into the moodle?

Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

If you really followed the instruction, you must have a success. After all there can be some difficulties, because I have made my own new block recently and had a few problems.

You have provided not much information about your trouble. So I will try to guide you in some way.

1. Your new block is a plugin, so have you installed it? It must happen automatically on loading Moodle website after copying all files and directories to the server.
2. After that you can go to: Home -> Site Administration -> Plugins -> Blocks -> Manage Blocks and check, if there is your new block and if it is visible.
3. If everything is alright you can manually add your new block to pages. In my Moodle I went to Home -> My home, pressed "Customized this page" and returned back to the Home Page and added the new block to the web page. Another way to add a new block to the Front Page (Home) is to go to Administration -> Front page settings -> Turn editing on.

If nothing helps, please write more details about your problem. My Moodle is 2.6, but there must not be any difference.

Comment: My newly created block is not visible in the Manage Blocks. I followed all instructions and created the four php files as they have mentioned. but it's not visible.

Comment: Could you show the code in your files? And where (what folders) they are. Maybe I could help then.